# b-form-select VUE bootstrap style/CSS issue

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, bootstrap-vue

I'm new working with VUE, but until the moment i already read and try some suggestions, but the issue continues.

I'm trying to use this one:
[Form Select - Bootstrap](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-select) ( like the example )

When i check my local host page I have:

[image: Wrong style]

In the code I have:

- Main.js

```
import {BootstrapVue, IconsPlugin, FormRatingPlugin, FormSelectPlugin  } from 'bootstrap-vue';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'

Vue.use(BootstrapVue)
Vue.use(IconsPlugin)
Vue.use(FormRatingPlugin)
Vue.use(FormSelectPlugin)

Vue.component('b-form-select', BFormSelect)
```

- Partner.js

```
[template]
<b-form-select 
    v-model="selected2" 
    id="socioPack"  
    name="socioPack" 
    :options="options2">
</b-form-select>
<div class="mt-3">Selected: <strong>{{ selected2 }}</strong></div>
</div>


[data()]

selected2: null,
options2: [
    { value: null, text: 'Please select some item' },
    { value: 'a', text: 'This is First option' },
    { value: 'b', text: 'Default Selected Option' },
    { value: 'c', text: 'This is another option' },
    { value: 'd', text: 'This one is disabled', disabled: true }
]
```

Can someone give me a tip?

Let me know if more details needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BootstrapVue is built for Bootstrap 4.

My guess is you've installed Bootstrap 5 by mistake, which has a different syntax for selects.

If you're using npm run `npm install bootstrap@4.5.3` to install the latest supported version of Bootstrap and it should display corerctly.

Comment: Before run de NPM, one more question.

But everything else work correctly. This "change" is only on Selects sintax?

Comment: No. There's a lot of stuff that will be different. You can read more in the V5 [migration guide](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/migration/)

Comment: Thanks for you answer. The NPM command resolve the issue. Any suggestion to validate the Input-forms/Select-forms ?

Comment: this is the correct answer. I remember I encountered this before and this answer reminded me. I am surprised this is not even mentioned in the BootstrapVue official docs